# Gradle - using a function from within Ant

Tags: function, gradle, groovy, ant

I have a Gradle script with few invocations of XJC to generate JAXB classes from XSD.

I thought I could parametrize these invocations and reuse the common code.

So I created a function:

```
ext.generateJaxbClasses = { HashMap params ->
    project.ant {
        ...
```

And then I wanted to use it:

```
task genJaxb {

    ext.generic = [
        schema: "..."
    ]

    doLast() {
        ext.generateJaxbClasses(jaxbSetA)
        ext.generateJaxbClasses(jaxbSetB)
    }
```

But I get this error:

```
> No signature of method: org.gradle.internal.extensibility.DefaultExtraPropertiesExtension.generateJaxbClasses() is applicable for argument types: (LinkedHashMap) values: [[...]]
```

How can I use the function within a task definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `project.ext.generateJaxbClasses(jaxbSetA)`

Using `ext` inside the task resolves to searching for the property inside the task's extension container.

---

See [`ExtensionAware`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.ExtensionAware.html).

I would suggest using an actual free function inside the project rather than using extensions as it can lead to this kind of frustration.

```
def generateJaxbClasses(HashMap params) {
    project.ant {...}
}
```